# Copy select options to onother one except option selected in the first one

Tags: jquery, html, web

Using jquery I need to create several `select`. Each of them have to copying the previous `select options` except the ones already selected by the user. Note: This will happen each time any of the `option` selected change.

Pick option #1

```
<select id='select1'>
<option selected>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Result: then 
Pick option #2

```
<select id='select2'>
<option selected>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Result

```
<select id='select3'>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('select')
    .on('change', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .next('select')
            .html($this.find('option:not(:selected)').clone());
    });
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lwzdx1k/).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.